# Problems with UIScrollView - Next View Controller is resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a resized a `View Controller` in order to make room for a `UIScrollView`. On this `ScrollView` I have a button that triggers a segue. The problem is when I create this segue, the destination `View Controller` is also resizing. Why is that, and how can I prevent it?

Hank

Comment: Could it be that you have resized a `UIView` and not a `UIViewController`? Because I'm not aware of any method to resize the view controller itself. (Where would you place your `UIScrollView` then?) A screenshot might be helpful.

Comment: Under "Simulated metrics" I choosed freeform as size, and then I could change the length of the View Controller.

Comment: turn off UseAutolayout it might be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, but where did you place your scroll view then?

Answer (score 0):

Untick the autoresizeSubview option for the parent view on top of which, you are adding the viewController.